# Tailwind problem with horizontal scroll outside screen (overflow)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a React-based NextJS application using Tailwind CSS. There is a page component that shows a list of people sorted from A to Ö (Swedish alphabet). When using mobile view, the UX states that the list of alphabetical letters should be visible on a single row and be scollable with arrows or finger on screen.

Problem: When in mobile view, the list starts at letter J, rather than letter A. Probably because it spans or overflows outside screen. User is unable to scroll to to the letter A (see pic).

Question: How can I fit the alphabet into the scrolling distance, how to get it to scroll further back to the first letter, or better yet, have it start at the letter A?

Mobile view

[image: Mobile view]

When in Desktop resolution

[image: When in Desktop resolution]

My current code for the LetterMeny component.

```
'use client';

import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { cn } from '@/utils/classnames';
import NavigateIcon from './icons/NavigateIcon';

const Letters = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'f',
  'g',
  'h',
  'i',
  'j',
  'k',
  'l',
  'm',
  'n',
  'o',
  'p',
  'q',
  'r',
  's',
  't',
  'u',
  'v',
  'w',
  'x',
  'y',
  'z',
  'å',
  'ä',
  'ö',
];

type Props = {
  currentElementIndexInViewport: number;
  activeLetters: string[];
};

const LetterMenu: React.FC<Props> = ({ currentElementIndexInViewport, activeLetters }) => {
  const carousel = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);
  const letterMenuRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [isSticky, setIsSticky] = useState(false);
  const [isAtStart, setIsAtStart] = useState(true);
  const [isAtEnd, setIsAtEnd] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const targetId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href')?.substring(1);
    const targetElement = targetId ? document.getElementById(targetId) : null;

    if (targetElement) {
      targetElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  };

  const updateButtonVisibility = () => {
    if (carousel.current) {
      const isStart = carousel.current.scrollLeft === 0;
      const isEnd =
        carousel.current.scrollLeft + carousel.current.offsetWidth === carousel.current.scrollWidth;
      setIsAtStart(isStart);
      setIsAtEnd(isEnd);
    }
  };

  const handleClickNext = () => {
    carousel.current?.scrollBy(300, 0);
    updateButtonVisibility();
  };

  const handleClickPrev = () => {
    carousel.current?.scrollBy(-300, 0);
    updateButtonVisibility();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateButtonVisibility(); // Kollar startposition
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (letterMenuRef.current) {
        setIsSticky(window.scrollY >= letterMenuRef.current.offsetTop);
      }
    };

    const handleCarouselScroll = () => {
      updateButtonVisibility();
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={letterMenuRef}
      className={cn('sticky top-0 z-10 w-screen bg-white', {
        'shadow-custom': isSticky,
      })}
    >
      {!isAtStart && (
        <button
          className="prev space-between absolute left-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 cursor-pointer content-center rounded-full px-2"
          onClick={handleClickPrev}
          aria-label="vänster"
        >
          <div className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-full border border-transparent bg-black bg-opacity-20 px-4 shadow-lg">
            <NavigateIcon direction="left" variant="secondary" />
          </div>
        </button>
      )}
      {/* Vi har här valt att ha skräddarsydd inline-styling i CSS då det endast gäller denna komponenten */}
      <ul
        ref={carousel}
        className="carousel flex justify-center gap-[0.624rem] overflow-x-auto scroll-smooth py-4"
      >
        {Letters.filter((letter) => activeLetters.includes(letter)).map((letter, letterIndex) => (
          <li key={`nav_${letter}`}>
            <Link
              href={`#${letter}`}
              onClick={handleClick}
              className={`focus:ring-blue-500 rounded-full font-livvic text-xl font-bold uppercase underline focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-greenblue-primary sm:p-4 ${
                activeLetters[currentElementIndexInViewport] === letter
                  ? 'active bg-greenblue-1.45 p-2 no-underline'
                  : ''
              }`}
              style={{
                width: '2.1rem',
                height: '2.1rem',
                display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
              }}
              tabIndex={0}
            >
              {letter}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      {!isAtEnd && (
        <button
          className="next absolute right-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 cursor-pointer content-center justify-center rounded-full px-4 shadow"
          onClick={handleClickNext}
          aria-label="höger"
        >
          <NavigateIcon direction="right" variant="secondary" />
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LetterMenu;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is likely due to the initial scroll position of your scrollable list. When the component mounts, it might not be scrolled all the way to the start.

To ensure that the list starts at the first letter, you can programmatically scroll the list to the start when the component mounts. You can do this by adding a line of code in your useEffect hook that runs on component mount.

Try This:

````
useEffect(() => {
    // Scroll to start when component mounts
    if (carousel.current) {
        carousel.current.scrollLeft = 0;
    }

    updateButtonVisibility(); // Check start position
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (letterMenuRef.current) {
        setIsSticky(window.scrollY >= letterMenuRef.current.offsetTop);
      }
    };

    const handleCarouselScroll = () => {
      updateButtonVisibility();
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, []);```
````

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately it's not working, component is loading the alphabet and the position is set to 0 at start. No idea why it does not scroll all the way back. [Updated original question with image]